# Multiple categories in vaadin column chart?

Tags: angular, vaadin, vaadin-charts

I'm trying to build a chart like this:
[image: chart1]
using vaadin-charts for angular2, except now I've got two colors because I'm comparing two different sources.  I've got the months showing up correctly, but I can't figure out how to categorize the months into quarter.

[image: chart2]

https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/charts/webcomponents-api/charts-configuration.html#charts.configuration.axes.categories

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<vaadin-column-chart>
    <chart-title>Distributions</chart-title>
    <x-axis>
        <categories>Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun</categories>
    </x-axis>
    <y-axis>
      <title>Value</title>
    </y-axis>
    <data-series name="exponential" [data]="exponential">
    </data-series>

    <data-series name="incremental" [data]="incremental">
    </data-series>
  </vaadin-column-chart>
```

Comment: If the solution below helped you, please make sure to upvote/accept, so other's can benefit from the solution.

Answer (score 0):

With [**Highcharts-Chart**](https://github.com/avdaredevil/highcharts-chart) you can do this like:

```js
/* ==================================================||
 These can all be data-binded in a polymer app
 Example: <highcharts-chart id='chart' type="column" title="Distributions" x-axis="[[xAxisConfig]]" data="[[multiSeriesData]]" plot-options="[[joinedBarsConfig]]" y-label="Value" legend></highcharts-chart>
|| ==================================================*/

//Bind Data
chart.data = [
  {name: 'exponential', data: [1,2,4,8,16]},
  {name: 'incremental', data: [0,1,2,3,4], color: '#ec6464'},
]

//Bind PlotOptions for thin, connected bars
chart.plotOptions = {column: {
  pointPadding: 0,
  borderWidth: 0,
}}

//Make x-axis categorical
chart.xAxis = {categories: ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun"]}
```

```html
<base href="https://user-content-dot-custom-elements.appspot.com/avdaredevil/highcharts-chart/v2.0.1/highcharts-chart/">
<link rel="import" href="highcharts-chart.html">

<highcharts-chart id='chart' type="column" title="Distributions" y-label="Value" legend></highcharts-chart>
```

**Click Run code snippet to see the chart!**

That's it! There are more examples [**here**](http://avdaredevil.github.io/highcharts-chart/) with real-time data. And here's [**the component page**](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/avdaredevil/highcharts-chart).